# Django - UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: python, django, debugging, django-models, frameworks

I could'nt solve my problem even if I looked other people who had this problem.

How to create an id with foreign key? And how can I use the id?

This is my code:

```
class Receipt(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, primary_key=True)
    vat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    total_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class ReceiptItem(models.Model):
    receipt_id = models.ForeignKey('Receipt', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    vat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    vat_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    sub_total = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    vat_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0, primary_key=True)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: migros_product.amount
```

Comment: I think only one field can be `primary_key`

Comment: The error is thrown on an other `model`. You have a model called`MigrosProduct` with the field `amount`. And I'm not sure why you are using so many `primary_key`s

Comment: I edited my code. Deleted the primary keys the unnecessary ones. still doesn't work

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question but you can delete all `primary_key` definitions. Django adds a field called `id` by default. Most of the time you won't need any other definition.

Comment: because you set a default of 0 to a primary_key, so it can only create 1 record with amount = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    vat_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0, primary_key=True)
```

Amount is set as `primary key`, which means that **the database will only allow 1 record per value of amount**.

**BUT**, you've also set a `default` value of 0, so your DB can only create 1 record with amount = 0, whenever the amount value is not provided.

You must decide what you want. If the amount uniqueness matters, then remove default=0 and put null=True, blank=True, for example.

Comment: so How can I fix it ? sorry Im newbie on django and python.

Comment: @Kaan San you can remove all `primary_key` definitions in your code unless you have a very good reason to keep them. Django adds a primary key by default.